# create custom shortcode wp and put php code in

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

i use **ACF** plugin and i want put this query in shortcode. but i have a problem.
**(not output anything)**

```
    add_shortcode('pishnahadi' , 'kn_inline_related');
global $post;
function kn_inline_related( $atts ) {
$html= '';
$posts = get_field('pishnahadi', false, false);
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post__in' => $posts, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'post__in', 'order' => 'ASC' ));

if($loop->have_posts()) {
     $html .= '<div class="rel-posts">';

        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

             $html .= '<div class="related-post">';
                    $html .=  '<h3><a href="' .the_permalink get_permalink() . '">' . the_title( '', '', false ) . '</a></h3>';
             $html .=  '</div>';

        endwhile;

$html .= '</div>';
} wp_reset_query();
}
return $html;
}
```

update: (The below code is correct and worked)

```
add_shortcode('pishnahadi' , 'kn_inline_related');
global $post;
function kn_inline_related( $atts ) {
$html= '';
$posts = get_field('pishnahadi', false, false);
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post__in' => $posts, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'post__in', 'order' => 'ASC' ));

if($loop->have_posts()) {
     $html .= '<div class="rel-posts">';

        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

             $html .= '<div class="related-post">';
                    $html .=  '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . the_title( '', '', false ) . '</a></h3>';
             $html .=  '</div>';

        endwhile;

$html .= '</div>';
} wp_reset_query();
return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_permalink()` **echoes** the output, and so does `the_title()` by default. So you should use [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) and [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/):

```php
$html .=  '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>';
```

Or use `the_title()` with the *third* [parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/#parameters) set to `false` to return and not echo the output:

```php
$html .=  '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . the_title( '', '', false ) . '</a></h3>';
```

**Update:** The `return $html;` (in your original non-edited question) was actually outside the function and that would result the shortcode to give you no output! So make sure that it's inside the function in your actual code. :) And for secondary/custom `WP_Query` instances like your `$loop` variable, you just need to call `wp_reset_postdata()` and not `wp_reset_query()` since secondary queries don't touch the (global) `$wp_query` variable. Unless of course, in your code, you modified that variable. But why would you do that.

Comment: this not output anything

Comment: Try adding `global $post;` at the top of your function.

Comment: There is still a problem. Even with the exception of permalink and title, the Div are not displayed in the output

Comment: Edit the question and add your current code, but in the question, the `return $html;` is outside the function. And I'm no longer getting any issues after using the non-echoing functions. And you can try clearing your site/browser caches.

Comment: TNX , worked. return $html; was outside the function.

Comment: Okay, I saw that "this is edited", but it would've been better if you appended the updated code at the bottom in the question. Anyway, I revised the answer because I actually thought the `return $html;` issue was just a typo in the question. :) Sorry about that!